# How to split a key from http request directory?

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

I have a incoming http POST request which post data to a given key in database, for example, curl POST 127.0.0.1/post/1 -d "value = 5", this would put value 5 to position where key = 1, I'm wondering how can I handle that command in java servlet, like split the key and value from curl command? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a servlet where you overwrite doPost():

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
  String value = request.getParameter("value");
...
}
```